# <context:property-placeholder loading from the filesystem

Tags: spring, properties

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath:test.properties" />
```

Above mentioned way of loading the property files from contex:property-placeholder works just fine. What I want to do is loading the property file from the file system.

Let's say I have the file in C drive `C:\spring\test.properties`. Here how can I load the file using  `context:property-placeholder`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `file:` URL instead of a `classpath:` one

```
<context:property-placeholder ignore-unresolvable="true"
     location="file:/C:/spring/test.properties" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Give properties to web application(Spring based) from filesystem(External Location)

1) specify placeholder in applications root xml as

2)define enviornment name as "config" in server's context.xml and give path of file

spring.xml

**file:#{contextJndi.lookup('java:comp/env/config')}**

context.xml

**Environment name="config" override="false" type="java.lang.String"           value="D:\config.properties"/>**