# CXF with Camel - HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, apache-camel, cxf

I am trying to implement a module to send messages from a CXF client to a server (SOAP endpoint) using HTTPS. I am able to achieve this by following the guide here: https://camel.apache.org/how-to-switch-the-cxf-consumer-between-http-and-https-without-touching-the-spring-configuration.html

The following configuration is key:

```
<ctx:property-placeholder location="classpath:orderEntry.cfg" />
<!-- other properties -->
<http:conduit name="{http://www.company.com/product/orderEntry/service/1}OrderEntry.http-conduit">
    <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true">
      <sec:trustManagers>
        <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="${trustStore.password}" file="${trustStore.file}"/>
      </sec:trustManagers>
      <!-- other config -->
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
</http:conduit>
```

The above configuration refers to a config file that has these properties stored:

```
orderEntry.cfg
--------------
endpointUri=https://localhost:8181/OrderEntry
trustStore.password=password
trustStore.file=etc/myApp.ts
```

As noted earlier, I am able to send messages via https when I follow the guide.

But I am concerned about the password being stored in plain text here. Is there a way that I can have the password wired from Java code (which can probably read the password from an encrypted source) and provide it to the http conduit when it needs it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried location attribute value with `file` prefix?

E.g. `location="file:/my/custom/location/orderEntry.cfg"`

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303537

Update:
If it works with your custom bean, you can try create trust managers as a bean and inject it into the conduit configuration like bellow:

blueprint.xml

```
<bean id="serviceTrustManager"
      class="my.app.security.KeyStores" factory-method="loadTrustManagers">
    <argument index="0" value="${my.app.service.trustStorePath}"/>
    <argument index="1" value="${my.app.service.trustStoreEncryptedPassword}"/>
</bean>
<http:conduit name="{http://www.company.com/product/orderEntry/service/1}OrderEntry.http-conduit">
    <http:tlsClientParameters disableCNCheck="true">
        <sec:trustManagers ref="serviceTrustManager"/>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
</http:conduit>
```

Java code:

```
public class KeyStores {
    public static TrustManager[] loadTrustManagers(String trustStorePath, String trustStoreEncryptedPassword) {
        String trustStoreDecryptedPassword = PasswordDescriptor.decryptPassword(trustStoreEncryptedPassword); //Password decryption logic here
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStores.loadKeyStore("JKS", trustStorePath, trustStoreDecryptedPassword); //IO logic here
        TrustManagerFactory trustFactory;
        try {
            trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustFactory.init(trustStore);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return trustFactory.getTrustManagers();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I tried using the property placeholder to use the file and it is able to pick the property. However, my need to have it encrypted is still not satisfied. I tried to override the "convertProperties" method (as seen here: https://kayalvizhiameen.blogspot.in/2014/04/handling-obfuscated-property-values-in.html) but that is not helping the http:conduit element - however, it works for the beans that I initialize myself.

Comment: I will try your updated suggestion and let you know. Thanks!!

Comment: @Ram Hey. And how did it go?

Comment: Sorry. Did not get a chance to try this out yet. Will do so soon and let you know.